# ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: mysql, sqoop

I am using shared node cluster

Hadoop 2.5.0-cdh5.3.2

Please share the names all compatible version of MySql jar files to be loaded and all the path folders for any successful import and export between HDFS and MySQL.

I am currently getting below error message

ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not     load db driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

so far, I have loaded MySql connector and hadoop jar files in /usr/lib/sqoop/lib

mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin
hadoop-core-1.0.3

Please let me know if I need to add more files and specify the path
Is t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a version incompatibility issue, then you can give a try to mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar as I am using mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar with sqoop version 1.4.5. For me, it works for both data import and export use cases.